# Delphi XE2: firemonkey and IDirect3DDevice9

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey

How can I access to global IDirect3DDevice9 object in firemonkey 3D form directly ? is it possible ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access"?  Are you trying to embed a D3D9 rendering context in a FireMonkey form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have access to DirectX interfaces using these properties:

`TCustomDX9Context.SharedDevice: IDirect3DDevice9;` |
`TCustomDX9Context.Direct3D9Obj: IDirect3D9 ;`

To access the current context of your application use: '[Form.Context :TContext3D](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types3D.TContext3D)'. TCustomDX9Context is a descendant of TContext3D, you have to test first which context device your application is currently using. It could be one of these classes:

1. [TCustomDX9Context](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Context.DX9.TCustomDX9Context)  //Windows
2. TCustomDX10Context  //Windows
3. TCustomContextOpenGL  //Mac

Good luck!